# Using cursor for loop to get data

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I want to select all employees that the contract is about to expire
then if I get one employee or more then I want to send notification to their managers using email , SMS ,ESS or mobile after checking the value of them and must equal yes then I call the sending function
I tried to do that using cursor for loop but I got more than one error
can anyone help me?

```
create or replace function NOTIFICATION_SENDING(P_NOTIF_ID    NUMBER) return NUMBER
IS
    V_EMP           NUMBER;
    V_USER          NUMBER;
    V_EMAIL         VARCHAR2(1);
    V_SMS           VARCHAR2(1);
    V_ESS           VARCHAR2(1);
    V_MOBILE        VARCHAR2(1);
    CURSOR C1 IS
        SELECT EMP_ID FROM HR_EMP_CONTRACT_HEADER 
        where months_between(EDATE,sysdate) >=1
        and months_between(EDATE,sysdate)  <= 3;

    CURSOR C2 IS
        SELECT USER_ID from NL_NOTIF_EMP_HEADER
        where NOTIF_ID = P_NOTIF_ID;
    
BEGIN
    for i in C1 LOOP
        V_EMP := i.EMP_ID;
    END LOOP;
   
    IF V_EMP is not null THEN
        for i in C2 LOOP
            V_USER := i.USER_ID;
        END LOOP;
        
        IF V_USER IS NOT NULL THEN 
            SELECT EMAIL , SMS , ESS , MOBILE  
            INTO V_EMAIL , V_SMS , V_ESS , V_MOBILE
            from NL_NOTIF_EMP_HEADER
            where NOTIF_ID = P_NOTIF_ID;

            IF V_EMAIL = 'Y'  THEN
                NOTIF_EMAIL_SENDING(P_NOTIF_ID ,V_USER );
            END IF;
        
            IF  V_SMS = 'Y' THEN
                NOTIF_SMS_SENDING(P_NOTIF_ID ,V_USER );
            END IF;
            
            IF  V_ESS = 'Y' THEN
                NOTIF_ESS_SENDING(P_NOTIF_ID ,V_USER );
            END IF;
               
            IF  V_MOBILE = 'Y' THEN
                NOTIF_MOBILE_SENDING(P_NOTIF_ID ,V_USER );
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END NOTIFICATION_SENDING;
```

This the code I used

Comment: "I got more than one error". Did you consider sharing those errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of your code:

- you use cursor loops in a wrong manner, as your code affects only **one** (the **last**) value retrieved by both cursors

  - I don't know why you chose to fetch `user_id` in cursor and all other values in standalone `select` statement; seems to be unnecessary
- that's a function, and you aren't returning anything so Oracle must be complaining about it
- separate `if`s suggest that manager wants to be (and will be) notified in many possible ways. If that's not what you wanted, consider using IF-ELSIF instead

---

To me, it is unclear what `nl_notif_emp_header` contains nor what `p_notif_id` parameter represents. I *think* that it contains only one row for each `p_notif_id` value, saying that manager identified by `user_id` wants to get notification by ANY (can be none, one, or all four) way available.

As you aren't returning anything, I'd say that procedure suits better.

In my example, I'm

- looping (unnecessary) (`cur_n`) through `nl_notif_emp_header`, just to avoid declaration of 5 local variables and use cursor variable instead
- looping (`cur_e`) through employees that satisfy condition and - depending on all ways of notification - sending it to manager

  - it is unclear what `notif_xxx_sending` procedures do. I'd expect them to accept *manager* (who is to be notified) and *employee* info (so that manager knows which employee it is about), while you're passing `p_notif_id` parameter value (?!? Why?) and manager ID (that's OK). Therefore, I added yet another parameter in my example; can't tell whether that's OK or not

So:

```
create or replace procedure NOTIFICATION_SENDING (P_NOTIF_ID in number)
is
begin
  -- CUR_N returns only one row, but - instead of declaring bunch of local
  -- variables, I'm using a one-time cursor loop
  for cur_n in (select user_id, email, sms, ess, mobile
                from nl_notif_emp_header
                where notif_id = p_notif_id
               )
  loop
    -- employees that satisfy condition
    for cur_e in (select emp_id
                  from hr_emp_contract_header
                  where months_between(edate, sysdate) between 1 and 3
                 )
    loop
      if cur_n.email = 'Y' then 
         notif_email_sending (p_notif_id, cur_n.user_id, cur_e.emp_id);
      end if;
      
      if cur_n.sms = 'Y' then
         notif_sms_sending (p_notif_id, cur_n.user_id, cur_e.emp_id);
      end if;
      
      -- etc., for all ways of notification
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
/
```